# NameError in Python for a function call

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a new button in Tkinter.  I have to define a delete function and use the passed information.  I am running into indentation errors when I'm defining variables.  You might have seen this code before in Codemy Image Viewer App at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg4c92pNFeo

```
def delete(image_number):
    global the_picture
    global button_forward
    global button_back
    
    os.remove(names[image_number])
    button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1))
    button_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: back(image_number-1))
```

However, I get an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\Programming\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Rizilip\.spyder-py3\ImageForPlanner.py", line 84, in <lambda>
    button_delete = Button(root, text="DESTROY", command=lambda: delete(image_number))
NameError: name 'image_number' is not defined
```

So can anyone shed some light on what is going on?  Why is adding code to this function so temperamental?  Why can't it locate the image_number?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? I imagine `image_number` is not being maintained in your variable scope (if it's even defined).

Comment: That error doesn't belong to that code. For one, the error mentions `button_delete` but your code doesn't show that button. I don't think it's possible for the code you posted to give the error you says it does, Please provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are getting error for line no 84 and not inside delete().I guess there is issue with below line.

```
button_delete = Button(root, text="DESTROY", command=lambda: delete(image_number))
```

Here the `image_number`variable is not defined. You can try changing line as below

```
button_delete = Button(root, text="DESTROY", command=lambda: delete(2))
```

I guess this will solve your issue.